# Display PHP Menu Stored in an Array and Looped

Tags: php, html, array

I'm creating a PHP website for a non-profit. They have some restrictions (no MySQL or pre-installed CMS) so I'm creating a CSS menu displayed by an unordered list where all of the elements are stored in a multi-dimensional array.

I've gotten it to work but being new to PHP, I'm certain it's not optimized to run as smoothly as possible. Also, I feel I've hacked my way through the first and last elements.

Here's the array:

```
<?php
$siteURL = "http://www.mysite.org/";

$menu = array
   (
   //"Name","URL",ID,Level,Seq,Under,Target,Display
   //First Menu
   array("TOP1",$siteURL."top1.php",1,1,1,0,0,true),
   array("SUB1a",$siteURL."sub1a.php",2,2,1,1,0,true),
   array("SUB1b",$siteURL."sub1b.php",3,2,2,1,0,true),
   array("SUB1c",$siteURL."sub1c.php",4,2,3,1,0,true),
   array("SUB1d","http://www.externalsite.org/",5,2,4,1,1,true),
   array("SUB1e","http://www.externalsite.org/",6,2,5,1,1,true),
   array("SUB1f",$siteURL."sub1f.php",7,2,6,1,0,true),

   //Second Menu
   array("TOP2",$siteURL."top2.php",8,1,2,0,0,true),
   array("SUB2a","http://www.externalsite.org/",9,2,1,8,1,true),
   array("SUB2b",$siteURL."sub2b.php",10,2,2,8,0,true),
   array("SUB2c","http://www.externalsite.org/",11,2,3,8,1,true),
   array("SUB2d","http://www.externalsite.org/",12,2,4,8,1,true),

   //Third Menu
   array("TOP3",$siteURL."top3.php",13,1,3,0,0,true),
   array("SUB3a","http://www.externalsite.org/",14,2,1,13,1,true),
   array("SUB3b","http://www.externalsite.org/",15,2,2,13,1,true),
   array("SUB3c","http://www.externalsite.org/",16,2,3,13,1,true),
   array("SUB3d","http://www.externalsite.org/",17,2,4,13,1,true),

   //Fourth Menu
   array("TOP4",$siteURL."top4.php",18,1,4,0,0,true),
   array("SUB4a",$siteURL."downloads/sub4a.pdf",19,2,1,18,0,true),
   array("SUB4b",$siteURL."sub4b.php",20,2,2,18,0,true),

   //Fifth Menu
   array("TOP5",$siteURL."top5.php",21,1,5,0,0,true),

   //Sixth Menu
   array("TOP6",$siteURL."top6.php",22,1,6,0,0,false),

   //Seventh Menu
   array("TOP7",$siteURL."top7.php",23,1,7,0,0,false),

   //Eighth Menu
   array("TOP8","http://www.externalsite.org/",24,1,8,0,1,true),

   );
?>
```

And here's the logic:

```
<ul>
<?php
$count = count($menu);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $count) {
    if (($menu[$i][3]===1) && ($menu[$i][7]===true)) {
        if ($menu[$i][6]===1) {
            echo "<li><a href=\"".$menu[$i][1]."\" target=\"_blank\">".$menu[$i][0]."</a><ul>\n";
        }
        else {
            echo "<li><a href=\"".$menu[$i][1]."\">".$menu[$i][0]."</a><ul>\n";
        }
        for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++){
            if (($menu[$j][5]===$menu[$i][2]) && ($menu[$j][7]===true)) {
                if ($menu[$j][6]===1) {
                    echo "<li><a href=\"".$menu[$j][1]."\" target=\"_blank\">".$menu[$j][0]."</a></li>\n";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<li><a href=\"".$menu[$j][1]."\">".$menu[$j][0]."</a></li>\n";
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</ul></li>';
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
</ul>
```

I had a hard time finding a relevant post. I'd appreciate some help or even just validation that I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Just wanted to tell you that it's a nice little first-post you have here. It seems like you have understood exactly what this site is about.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure for optimization but for readability and maintenance I would use a Class and create the menu items as objects instead of multi-dimension arrays.

```
class MenuItem {

  protected $id;
  protected $name;
  protected $url;
  protected $level;
  protected $seq;
  protected $under;
  protected $target;
  protected $display;

  public function __construct($name, $url, $id, $level, $seq, $under, $target, $display) {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->url = $url;
    $this->level = $level;
    $this->seq = $seq;
    $this->under = $under;
    $this->target = $target;
    $this->display = $display;
  }

  public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
  }

  public function getName() {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function getUrl() {
    return $this->url;
  }

  public function getLevel() {
    return $this->level;
  }

  public function getSeq() {
    return $this->seq;
  }

  public function getUnder() {
    return $this->under;
  }

  public function getTarget() {
    return $this->target;
  }

  public function getDisplay() {
    return $this->display;
  }

}
```

And so your creation code would become:

```
$siteURL = "http://www.mysite.org/";

$menu = array
   (
   //"Name","URL",ID,Level,Seq,Under,Target,Display
   //First Menu
   new MenuItem("TOP1",$siteURL."top1.php",1,1,1,0,0,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB1a",$siteURL."sub1a.php",2,2,1,1,0,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB1b",$siteURL."sub1b.php",3,2,2,1,0,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB1c",$siteURL."sub1c.php",4,2,3,1,0,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB1d","http://www.externalsite.org/",5,2,4,1,1,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB1e","http://www.externalsite.org/",6,2,5,1,1,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB1f",$siteURL."sub1f.php",7,2,6,1,0,true),

   //Second Menu
   new MenuItem("TOP2",$siteURL."top2.php",8,1,2,0,0,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB2a","http://www.externalsite.org/",9,2,1,8,1,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB2b",$siteURL."sub2b.php",10,2,2,8,0,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB2c","http://www.externalsite.org/",11,2,3,8,1,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB2d","http://www.externalsite.org/",12,2,4,8,1,true),

   //Third Menu
   new MenuItem("TOP3",$siteURL."top3.php",13,1,3,0,0,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB3a","http://www.externalsite.org/",14,2,1,13,1,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB3b","http://www.externalsite.org/",15,2,2,13,1,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB3c","http://www.externalsite.org/",16,2,3,13,1,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB3d","http://www.externalsite.org/",17,2,4,13,1,true),

   //Fourth Menu
   new MenuItem("TOP4",$siteURL."top4.php",18,1,4,0,0,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB4a",$siteURL."downloads/sub4a.pdf",19,2,1,18,0,true),
   new MenuItem("SUB4b",$siteURL."sub4b.php",20,2,2,18,0,true),

   //Fifth Menu
   new MenuItem("TOP5",$siteURL."top5.php",21,1,5,0,0,true),

   //Sixth Menu
   new MenuItem("TOP6",$siteURL."top6.php",22,1,6,0,0,false),

   //Seventh Menu
   new MenuItem("TOP7",$siteURL."top7.php",23,1,7,0,0,false),

   //Eighth Menu
   new MenuItem("TOP8","http://www.externalsite.org/",24,1,8,0,1,true),

   );
```

Then you can access values in a more readable way. E.g.

```
foreach ($menu as $menuItem) {
  if (($menuItem->getLevel() === 1) && ($menuItem->getDisplay() === true)) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: You could extend MenuItem by adding a subMenu property - which is of type MenuItem - and instead of creating all your MenuItems in an array, add the sub menus to the parent.

Comment: Thanks! This works great for the the top-level menu items but I'm lost when it comes to the loop for the sub-menu items.